# Getting rid of a flame vine

Tags: landscaping, vines

We want to get rid of a flame vine.  It's been cut to the ground every few years, but always comes back with a vengeance.  How do we kill it or get rid of it forever?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Flame Vine or [Pyrostegia venusta](http://plants.ifas.ufl.edu/node/355) is sold as a dazzling addition to the Florida landscape at the same as it is described as invasive. It does not set seed but spreads by roots that  can be as long as 20 m (~60 feet). Sustained temperatures below 2 deg C kill top growth but it resprouts from roots.

Control is accomplished by:

- physical removal of all top growth
- from [here](http://www.se-eppc.org/wildlandweeds/pdf/fall2005-hutchinson-pp7-11.pdf)

> Garlon 4 (triclopyr, 10% product)mixed with Veg Oil (90%) was
>   successful in controlling flame vine. No resprouts (n= 25) were
>   recorded for stems cut and treated at the node with 10% Garlon 4.Vines
>   growing vertically above the cut were not treated and died.
>   However,resprouts were observed on untreated nodes > 0.75 m from the
>   treated node attached to the same root, indicating that herbicide
>   translocation may not occur from node to node. Thus, every node,
>   possibly thousands per hectare, must be treated for complete control.

- followup treatments with Roundup of the resprouts is necessary

Keep in mind that I do not know the regulations for applying pesticides where you live and you will probably need a licensed pesticide applicator to use Garlon ([triclopyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triclopyr)).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triclopyr